# Can I write an npm script that runs slightly different on Windows?

Tags: windows, node.js, environment-variables, npm

I am using the `scripts` feature of `npm` to conveniently start my service by typing `npm start`. In my `package.json` file, I have this:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "start": "NODE_PATH=. node index.js",
        ....
    }
}
```

The `NODE_PATH` is the troublesome part. I do this so I can write in my javascript files: `require('lib/mymodule');` instead of `require('../lib/mymodule');` or some variant. There is a different syntax for setting an environment variable for a command on Windows. It would be `cmd /C "set NODE_PATH=. && node index.js"`.

How can I accomplish running the right `start` command based on the operating system?

Comment: Are you mangling `NODE_PATH` for aesthetic purposes...?

Comment: I'm adding the current directory to the node path so that I can require relative to the top of my project. So technically for aesthetic purposes...